# tsql why not only unbounded following

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As I was checking the tsql syntax of the over clause here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

I noticed one may use UNBOUNDED PRECEDING to mean the same thing as
BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

On the other hand, one may not use UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING alone. Indeed I get a syntax error near FOLLOWING if I do this. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is consistent with doucmentation in the documentation you linked. Specifically see Note in General Remarks, the explicitly mentions your case.

If you're asking why it's implemented like this - well I have no idea.

Comment: Indeed I'm asking the reason it was implemented like this.